# What is wrong with my js script to show/hide div based on user inputselection?

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a country field and a state field. I want to show the state field when the user chooses United States. Otherwise, I want it to be hidden.

This is my  js script:

```
@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#Country").change(function () {
           var value = $("#Country").val()
           if (value === "1") {
               $("#State").show();
           }
           if (value != "1") {
               $("#State").hide();
           }
     });
        
</script>
@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

This is my cshtml page of the form.

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-4 mt-4">
    <label asp-for="Form.Country" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="Form.Country" class="form-control">
    <option disabled selected>Choose your Country</option>
    <option>Canada</option>
    <option>United States</option>
    <option>Mexico</option>
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="Form.Country" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-4 mt-4">
    <label asp-for="Form.State" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="Form.State" asp-items="Model.States" class="form-select">
        <option disabled selected>Choose your State</option>
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="Form.State" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: the script says, element with id Country, but in the cshtml file, I don't see in element with that id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To use `$("#Country")` and `$("#State")` you have to specify `id`'s for the `<select>` forms
2. To get the `.val()` of the selected item you have to specify `value` for each option

Your JS code may look like this:

```js
$("#State").hide();
    
$("#Country").change(function () {
  var value = $("#Country").val()
  if (value === "2") {
    $("#State").show();
  }
  else {
    $("#State").hide();
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-4 mt-4">
  <label asp-for="Form.Country" class="control-label"></label>
  <select asp-for="Form.Country" class="form-control" id="Country">
    <option disabled selected>Choose your Country</option>
    <option value="1">Canada</option>
    <option value="2">United States</option>
    <option value="3">Mexico</option>
  </select>
  <span asp-validation-for="Form.Country" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-4 mt-4">
  <label asp-for="Form.State" class="control-label"></label>
  <select asp-for="Form.State" asp-items="Model.States" class="form-select" id="State">
    <option disabled selected>Choose your State</option>
  </select>
  <span asp-validation-for="Form.State" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Following Code:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-4 mt-4">
    <label asp-for="Form.Country" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="Form.Country" class="form-control" id="Country">
    <option disabled selected>Choose your Country</option>
    <option value="0">Canada</option>
    <option value="1">United States</option>
    <option value="2">Mexico</option>
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="Form.Country" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-4 mt-4" id="state">
    <label asp-for="Form.State" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="Form.State" asp-items="Model.States" class="form-select">
        <option disabled selected>Choose your State</option>
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="Form.State" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#state{
  display:none
}
```

Jquery:

```
 $("#Country").change(function () {
   var value = $("#Country").val();
   console.log(value)
   if (value === "1") {
     $("#state").show();
   }
   if (value != "1") {
     $("#state").hide();
   }
 });
```